# Lib curl with openssl compilation fails

Tags: c++, curl

I want to build the lib curl 7.54.0 with openssl statically for a VS2015 project on win 7. I have built the openssl but unable to build the curl. It fails with error code U1077.

I am running following command in "Developer command prompt for VS2015",

G:\Libs\curl-7.54.0\winbuild>nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static WITH_SSL=static WITH_DEVEL="G:\Libs\openssl-1.0.1g\output" VC=14 ENABLE_WINSSL=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x86 GEN_PDB=no

It compiles some files then fails as follows,
Copying libs...
        rc /i../include /dDEBUGBUILD=0 /Fo ..\builds\libcurl-vc14-x86-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi-obj-curl\curl.res ..\src\curl.rc 'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1' Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Not sure how to fix this. Please suggest.

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 0):

I have been solving similar problem with another library. *rc.exe* is part of Windows SDK and I had to add path of *Windows SDK* to PATH environment variable.

In my case I have added this to PATH environment variable:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\

Hoping, it helps.
PM